# Obtain div opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple `div` that I want to get the opacity of with JavaScript.

I currently do this:

```
var d = document.getElementById('1').style.opacity;
    console.log(d); //blank
```

But the result in `console.log` is an empty line. Do I need to specifically put opacity in the CSS file or is it default any way?

My HTML & CSS:

```
.room{    
    width:90%;
    height:75px;
    border-radius:3px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

---

```
<div class="room" id="1">
       //content
</div>
```

Why is it recieving a blank result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

`var d = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('1')).opacity`

in replace of

`var d = document.getElementById('1').style.opacity;`

This will return the value of CSS properties *after* applying active stylesheets.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.getComputedStyle)

Comment: Ah so thats how you get values from CSS rather than inline style! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if your javascript is in the "head", then it's because the dom has not loaded yet. try placing the script after the div

Comment: It is called after a `windows.onload` it would also surely give a console error if the div id was not found.

Answer (score 0):

you're not specifying any opacity in that css as I see the file now